# How do I disable the button before finished animating

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimage

I'm using the code below. How can I disable the button before the Finish Animation effect? In that case when I clicked the button before finish animating than animation image restarts and it is not very smooth.

```
@IBAction func btn_LeeStatue(sender: AnyObject) {    
    lee_statue_img.animationImages = [
        UIImage(named: "lee_statueAni0001.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "lee_statueAni0002.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "lee_statueAni0003.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "lee_statueAni0004.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "lee_statueAni0005.png")!,
    ] 

    lee_statue_img.animationDuration = 3
    lee_statue_img.animationRepeatCount = 1
    lee_statue_img.startAnimating()     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIImageView image animation doesn't have a "completion handler". It is much more simple-minded than that.

If you want a completion handler, use some sort of animation that does have a completion handler.

(In your case, I don't see why you even need a completion handler. You know when this animation will end: X second from now. So just set an NSTimer to call you back then.)
so your code will be:

```
func showButton(timer : NSTimer) {
   YourButtonOutlet.enabled = true
   //this will enable you button again
}

@IBAction func btn_LeeStatue(sender: AnyObject) {    
lee_statue_img.animationImages = [
    UIImage(named: "lee_statueAni0001.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "lee_statueAni0002.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "lee_statueAni0003.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "lee_statueAni0004.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "lee_statueAni0005.png")!,
] 

//Disable the button
YourButtonOutlet.enabled= false
lee_statue_img.animationDuration = 3
lee_statue_img.animationRepeatCount = 1
lee_statue_img.startAnimating()
//set the timer for X seconds (4s in this example)  
let myTimer : NSTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4, target: self, selector: Selector("showButton:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

and you can also use dispatch after,
just add this function->

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

and you can call it like this->(0.75 is the time that the app should wait before executing whats in the closure)

```
delay(0.75, closure: {
    //write here the code to be executed after 0.75 second
    //in your case it will be YourButtonOutlet.enabled = true
})
```

**PS: you have to set `YourButtonOutlet.enabled = false` before the animation start**

Comment: thanks for comments Mr.Abida but i want more simple code.. is there no way more simple code? i do not want use NSTimer.. ;->

Comment: Belive me, using NSTimer is the easiest way, if you want to use completion handler(to be informed when the animation did finish, you have to use  another sort of animation )

Comment: In this day and age, I would opt for `dispatch_after()` instead of `NSTimer`... (my opinion)

Comment: thanks , i updated my answer with your suggestion, and yes its more elegant and useful to use  dispatch_after() instead of NSTimer

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to disable a button from users touch animate it then enable it to a user's touch. To do that you toggle the userInteractionEnabled property.

```
let button: UIButton = UIButton()
button.userInteractionEnabled = false
button.animateMethod()
button.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: i do not understand that code ;-0  i am starter pardon..       i want disable button during animating i insert that code not working ;-0

Comment: How do you create the button?

Comment: `@IBAction func btn_LeeStatue(sender: AnyObject)` I made the Button in **Main.stroryboard** and drag the button image on to **ViewController.swift** with press control key